# Unrecognized option: --spring.profiles.active=prod Openshift

Tags: spring, openshift, jhipster

When i deployed jhipster web application to OpenShift, my app page getting "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" and when I look at the log files, having the following problem;

```
==> app-root/logs/mapp.log <==
Unrecognized option: --spring.profiles.active=prod
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Is there any solution you know?

Comment: `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not an option recognized by the JVM. In order to set system properties use use `-D`. From the [Java 7 reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> -Dproperty=value
>
> Sets a system property value.
>
> If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the
>   string in double quotation marks:
>
> java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass

In this instance you would use:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

It can then be acquired in your application by using the `System` class:

```
System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")
```

Comment: Thats worked but now i got that warning "[WARN] org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Skipping [/var/lib/openshift/5495a4284382ecb8160001e5/app-root/runtime/repo/target/mapp-0‌​.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] because it does not denote a directory"

Comment: @mhmmd that's a different problem, isn't it? Post it as a new question.